# Remove 95 percent of highest count Kusto Query

Tags: azure-data-explorer, askql

I am trying to get the total count of a column by referrer and remove the top 95 percent of highest count, and only show the lowest count(5%) of referrer, any examples?

summarize count(id) by referrer
where count_id <5%

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how you do it (note that in my example I take 50th percentile, just because I don't want to type too much data to have a meaningful 5th percentile :)):

```
let YourTable = datatable(Name:string, NumCandies:long) [
    "John", 10,
    "Beth", 20,
    "Steven", 30,
    "Paul", 40,
    "Elsa", 50,
    "George", 60,
    "Martha", 70
];
let Percentile50 = toscalar(
    YourTable
    | summarize percentile(NumCandies, 50));
YourTable
| where NumCandies <= Percentile50
```

This will output:

```
| Name   | NumCandies |
|--------|------------|
| John   | 10         |
| Beth   | 20         |
| Steven | 30         |
| Paul   | 40         |
|--------|------------|
```

Comment: can you be more specific on how to get the chunk of rows that represent  5% of the total count?

Comment: I've updated the answer to have a complete example.

Comment: @M.E, Please accept the answer if helps (that's the StackOverflow way to say Thank You). I see you're a new user on StackOverflow, and there are several other questions that you asked and were answered, but you haven't accepted, nor commented why the answer doesn't suffice, please do. Thanks!